# filter unit tests in test explorer in visual studio 2012 by both property name and value

Tags: visual-studio-2012, test-explorer

Is there a way to filter tests in test explorer in visual studio 2012 by both property name and property value. Consider following properties on 4 distinct tests:

```
[TestPropertyAttribute("A", "1")]

[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "1")]

[TestPropertyAttribute("A", "2")]

[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "2")]
```

Is there an expression I can put in test explorer filter bar that will only how me tests that have property B with value 1? Something like: `trait:B=1`.

I know I can use `trait:B` to show all tests that have property B defined, or a property with value set to B. But I want to know if there is a way to only get tests decorated with:

```
[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "1")]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way of doing this, but there are several workarounds that can be used to achieve your needs.

**1. If you don't have any other traits (TestPropertyAttribute, TestCategory, Priority or Owner) on your tests, you can do it by defining two filters like this:**

```
Trait:"B" Trait:"1"
```

But you have to be careful, because that filter would also return all of theses tests:

```
[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "1")]
[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "10")]
[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "100")]
[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "21")]
[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "31")]
```

So in that case you would need to add some leading zeros to solve the problem:

```
[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "001")]
[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "010")]
[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "100")]
```

So you could use arcodingly with the filter:

```
Trait:"B" Trait:"001"
```

**2. If you are using other traits (TestPropertyAttribute, TestCategory, Priority or Owner) you have to be more specific with your own TestPropertyAttribute.**

Let's say you also have a numeric property which can be confused with your "B" trait Value. So you have to add the "B" to your trait value like this:

```
[TestPropertyAttribute("B", "B001")]
```

So you could be filtering then the following way:

```
Trait:"B001"
```

**Additionally**

Would recommend to read the following blog which has very useful information regarding this topic:

[How To Manage Unit Tests in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1 Part 1 Using Traits in the Unit Test Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/09/how-to-manage-unit-tests-in-visual-studio-2012-update-1-part-1-using-traits-in-the-unit-test-explorer.aspx)